# How can I route all traffic on my iPad through a proxy?

Tags: ipad, proxy

I have an iPad running iOS 8.1.2. I have added a manual proxy to the Wi-Fi connection but it seems that only the HTTP (port 80) and HTTPS (port 443) traffic is going through the proxy. Is it possible to pass all traffic through the proxy?

Comment: what other traffic is not going true proxy?

Comment: I don't know exactly because I can't see it. I'm trying to troubleshoot an app. It gets a lot of information from the internet but very little (almost none) via HTTP port 80.

Comment: How do I netstat on an iPad?

Answer (score 1):

The Proxy you add is a http proxy. Port is not the point. In the other word, other protocol except http traffic will not going through this proxy. for example Facebook App using SPDY protocol so this app "bypass" your proxy

Comment: The actuall question "Is it possible to pass all traffic through the proxy?" remains unaswered... So, is there a way?